# Clever asynchronous repaint in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent

I have a use-case coming from a GUI problem I would like to submit to your sagacity.

**Use case**

I have a GUI that displays a computation result depending on some parameters the user set in a GUI. For instance, when the user moves a slider, several events are fired, that all trigger a new computation. When the user adjust the slider value from A to B, a dozens of events are fired.

But the computation can take up to several seconds, whereas the slider adjustment can fire an event every few 100 ms.

How to write a proper Thread that would listen to these events, and kind of filter them so that the repaint of the results is lively? Ideally you would like something like

- start a new computation as soon as first change event is received;
- cancel the first computation if a new event is received, and start a new one with the new parameters;
- but ensure that the last event will not be lost, because the last completed computation needs to be the one with last updated parameters.

**What I have tried**

A friend of mine (A. Cardona) proposed this low level approach of an Updater thread that prevents too many events to trigger a computation. I copy-paste it here (GPL):

He puts this in a class that extends Thread:

```java
public void doUpdate() {
    if (isInterrupted())
        return;
    synchronized (this) {
        request++;
        notify();
    }
}

public void quit() {
    interrupt();
    synchronized (this) {
        notify();
    }
}

 public void run() {
    while (!isInterrupted()) {
        try {
            final long r;
            synchronized (this) {
                r = request;
            }
            // Call refreshable update from this thread
            if (r > 0)
                refresh(); // Will trigger re-computation
            synchronized (this) {
                if (r == request) {
                    request = 0; // reset
                    wait();
                }
                // else loop through to update again
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


public void refresh() {
    // Execute computation and paint it
    ...
}
```

Every-time an event is sent by the GUI stating that parameters have been changed, we call `updater.doUpdate()`. This causes the method `refresh()` to be called much less. 
But I have no control on this.

**Another way?**

I was wondering if there is another way to do that, that would use the jaca.concurrent classes. But I could not sort in the Executors framework what would be the one I should start with.

Does any of you have some experience with a similar use case?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using `Swing`, the `SwingWorker` provides capabilities for this, and you don't have to deal with the thread pool yourself.

Fire off a `SwingWorker` for each request. If a new request comes in and the worker is not done, you can `cancel()` it, and just start a new `SwingWorker`. Regarding what the other poster said, I don't think `publish()` and `process()` are what you are looking for (although they are also very useful), since they are meant for a case where the worker might fire off events faster than the GUI can process it.

```
ThingyWorker worker;

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if( worker != null ) worker.cancel();
    worker = new ThingyWorker();
    worker.execute();
}

class ThingyWorker extends SwingWorker<YOURCLASS, Object> {
    @Override protected YOURCLASS doInBackground() throws Exception {
        return doSomeComputation(); // Should be interruptible
    }   
    @Override protected void done() {
        worker = null; // Reset the reference to worker

        YOURCLASS data;

        try {
            data = get();
        } catch (Exception e) { 
            // May be InterruptedException or ExecutionException                
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }           

        // Do something with data
    }       
}
```

Both the action and the `done()` method are executed on the same thread, so they can effectively check the reference to whether there is an existing worker.

Note that effectively this is doing the same thing that allows a GUI to cancel an existing operation, except the cancel is done automatically when a new request is fired.

Comment: good solution. but it's unclear to me whether there's a small chance that after `worker1.cancel()`, `worker1.done()` is still executed, and it can be executed after `worker2.done()`, i.e. an older result overwrites a newer result. need a bit more investigation here.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem of how to batch the requests, to avoid the situation where you're cancelling and restarting the thread many times over some short period.

Comment: I don't think you can ever avoid canceling the requests, because you never know if some request is the last one. Sure, you can wait a bit before firing off workers, to see if more requests are coming, but that would just make the update slower.

Comment: @zhong.j.yu if even possible, seems very unlikely as `worker2.doInBackground()` will take much longer than `worker1.cancel()`. Also since the `cancel()`, `execute()` and `done()` are all in the event dispatch thread, it seems that `cancel()` should prevent `done()` from getting called if Swing is synchronizing properly. There is no race condition in the cancel here.

Answer (score 1):

I would provide a further degree of disconnect between the GUI and the controls by using a queue.

If you use a `BlockingQueue` between the two processes. Whenever the controls change you can post the new settings to the queue.

Your graphics component can read the queue whenever it likes and act on the arriving events or discard them as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I would look into SwingWorker.publish() (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html)

Publish allows the background thread of a SwingWorker object to cause calls to the process() method, but not every publish() call results in a process() call.  If multiple process calls are made before process() returns and can be called again, SwingWorker concatenates the parameters used for multiple publish calls into one call to process.

I had a progress dialog which displayed files being processed; the files were processed faster than the UI could keep up with them, and I didn't want the processing to slow down to display the file names; I used this and had process display only the final filename sent to process(); all I wanted in this case was to indicate to the user where the current processing was, they weren't going to read all the filenames anyway.  My UI worked very smoothly with this.

Comment: Thanks! Would it be applicable for something else than a GUI?

Comment: I don't think `process` and `publish` are what the OP is looking for. You can't update a `SwingWorker` with new events. In this case the problem is different: processing is slower than the actions triggered by the UI.

Comment: @AndrewMao good point -- publish/process is updating a UI due to processing, and this problem includes updating the processing from the UI.  The UI-generated events are already queued, of course; perhaps the program could receieve slider events until no more events are in the queue, then start processing on the most recent value since earlier ones are no longer relevant.  So I think my idea is relevant to updating the UI, but you are right that there is the UI-to-processing issue to consider separately.

Comment: @Jean-Yves I am not familiar with using SwingWorker for anything other than a UI, though I don't know that it can't be done.  I thought of another way to do things: let the slider kick off a timer; if the timer is already running, update its timeout.  When the timer expires, start processing.  That way only the last in a series of queued-up slider events get processed.

Comment: @Jean-Yves also look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/slider.html for information on the change event you can listen to from the slider; it has an example of one that is interested only in the "last" change made, i.e., not interested in all the events that happen while sliding to a final value, but interested in that value when the sliding stops.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the implementation of javax.swing.SwingWorker (source code in the Java JDK),
with a focus on the handshaking between two methods: *publish* and *process*.

These won't be directly applicable, as-is, to your problem - however they demonstrate how you might queue (publish) updates to a worker thread and then service them in your worker thread (process).

Since you only need the last work request, you don't even need a queue for your situation: keep only the last work request.  Sample that "last request" over some small period (1 second), to avoid stopping/restarting many many times every 1 second, and if it's changed THEN stop the work and restart.

---

The reason you don't want to use *publish* / *process* as-is is that *process* always runs on the Swing Event Dispatch Thread - not at all suitable for long running calculations.

Comment: This depends on how he uses it -- if all process does is update the UI, it is exactly what he wants.  He doesn't have to (and should not) do his long calculation there, I agree.  But it is exactly right for part of his problem.

Answer (score 0):

The key here is that you want to be able to cancel an ongoing computation. The computation must frequently check a condition to see if it needs to abort.

```
volatile Param newParam;

Result compute(Param param)
{
    loop
        compute a small sub problem
        if(newParam!=null) // abort
            return null;  

    return result
}
```

To handover param from event thread to compute thread

```
synchronized void put(Param param)  // invoked by event thread
    newParam = param;
    notify();

synchronized Param take()
    while(newParam==null)
        wait();
    Param param = newParam;
    newParam=null;
    return param;
```

And the compute thread does

```
public void run()
    while(true)
        Param param = take();
        Result result = compute(param);
        if(result!=null)
            paint result in event thread
```

Comment: I don't know about 'frequently check a condition', aka polling; this is what interrupts are for.

Comment: how do you interrupt a busy loop:?)